# Firebase-tools initializing error

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I'm building an web app that will use firebase as hosting and database. In order to do this, I need to create a project using `firebase init` but after doing that I can proceed to choose which features I want to choose, I get stuck in it and can't move through the options.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At that screen, you can use the up and down arrow keys to select the different Firebase features to set up, and use the space bar to toggle them.  After you've made your selection, press enter to continue.

If that doesn't work for you, please contact [support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/).

Comment: That's exactly what's (up and down)  not working. So I'll be contacting support

Comment: Also make sure your firebase-tools is fully up to date from npm.